# g++ cannot find the overloaded function after typecast

Tags: c++, g++, overloading

I have a overloaded function

```
void FuncGetSomething(string, double&)
void FuncGetSomething(string, int&)
void FuncGetSomething(string, bool&)
```

....
It is supposed to work this way

```
double myDbl = 0;
FuncGetSomething("Somename", myDbl) 
//to get the new value for myDbl in side the function, and the new value is preset earlier in the code
```

But for some reason, I saw someone write this

```
double myDlb = 0;
FuncGetSomething("Somename", (double)myDbl)
```

and this works in Visual Studio 2008.

However, when I trying to build the same thing in Linux (g++ 4.7.2), it complains

```
error: no matching function for call to  GetSomething(const char [8], double) can be found
```

Can anyone give me some ideas on why it works in VS08 and hwy it is not in Linux?
Is there anyway to make it also work in Linux?

Comment: `GetSomething` != `FuncGetSomething`

Comment: sorry that was a typo, I meant the same function

Answer (score 5):

The cast to `(double)` means it is creating a temporary object of type `double`. When you call the function, you are trying to bind a non-const reference to it, which is not allowed. This might help:

```
void f( double& ) {};

double d = 1.2;
f( d ); // allowed (1)
f( 1.2 ); // not allowed (2)
f( (double)d ); // not allowed, basically the same as (2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Actually, I understand why it is not allowed. What I don't understand is why the same code works in Visual Studio 08. Is there any kind of compiler flag that can affect this?

Comment: @user2800938 I don't use Windows/Visual Studio, so I can't test anything like that. What *might* help is to disable the MS-specific language extensions with `/Za`, give it a try if you haven't already. One of their extensions is described as "Non-ANSI casts to produce l-values", which looks suspiciously like your case.